# Ruby on Rails - PG Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

On Rails 4, hosted through Heroku. I've read a few threads about this problem but needed to make my own for clarification. Relevant models:

Submission:

```
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :organization
  belongs_to :division
```

In the submissions' index page, I list all the submissions made by the user, grouping by the `:contest_year` attribute and also the `:organization_id` attribute that the submission belongs to.

Submission Controller:

```
def index
  @paginate = current_user.submissions.group([:organization_id, 
  :contest_year]).includes(:organization).page(params[:page]).per(3).order('contest_year DESC')
end
```

(This index page has Kaminari's pagination functionality)

Index view:

```
<% @paginate.each do |contest| %>
  <div class="submissionheading"><h2><%= contest.contest_year %>: <%= contest.organization.name %></h2></div>
  <% current_user.submissions.includes(:submission_details, :user, category: :award).order('created_at DESC').where(organization_id: contest.organization_id, contest_year: contest.contest_year).in_groups_of(3, false) do |group| %>
    <div class="row">
    <% group.each do |submission| %>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <p class="bold"><%= submission.category.award.name %> <%= submission.category.code %>: <%= submission.category.name %></p>
        <p>Submitted By: <%= submission.user.first_name %> <%= submission.user.last_name %></p>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div><br/>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

<p><%= paginate @paginate %></p>
```

I get this error:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  column "submissions.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

IF I insert the `:id` attribute into the group part of that above controller code, it repeats the submission information for every submission. Here's an illustration:

What it should be doing normally (without `:id` in the group part):

[image]

What it does once I insert `:id` in the group part:

[image]

It iterates for every submission, not just once for the three submissions that have the same org/year in common. Basically, I don't want to add `:id` to the grouping but PG is throwing this error! How can I re-write my controller code so PG accepts it while keeping the grouping correct? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Either add `select('DISTINCT(submissions.id), submissions.*')` to the model finder or chain `uniq` onto it:

```
def index
  @paginate = current_user.submissions.uniq.group([:id, :organization_id, 
  :contest_year]).includes(:organization).page(params[:page]).per(3).order('contest_year DESC')
end
```

**Update:**

The problem is in your view code. You are iterating over the `@paginate` collection and then within it you are again calling `current_user.submissions`. Not sure what you're doing here but It's probably trippleing everything via the `in_groups_of(3)` call. Check that your `@paginate` collection is indeed unique and then debug your view code.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When I try adding uniq just like you did, it says "undefined method `group' for #<Array:0x14f4c4f8>"; when I try adding that select statement to the controller code it does not appear to have an effect, it still outputs duplicates. Any thoughts? Thanks again.

Comment: Good suggestion! I did so just now and that error went away. Unfortunately it also appears to have no affect, it is still duplicating.

Comment: Check the value in your controller by inspecting the @paginate variable. Your bug may be in your view. Please post you view code.

Comment: Sure thing, I have added it now.

Comment: I actually don't think that's true. The reason why is because I remove all that code so only the heading information is left (my original view snippet until I edited), to experiment to see if the problem is there. The headings are still being repeated without the additional code.